# Expectation of a norm of a vector $H\theta$ as multiplication of covariance matrix

Tags: probability, matrices

Let  $\theta $ be a gaussian random vector of length $l$ with covariance matrix $\Sigma_\theta$ = $\sigma_\theta ^2 \cdot I_{l\times l} $ and $E[\theta]=\underline{0}$.

Let $H_{l \times l}$ be a deterministic matrix.

suppose $y = H\theta $ , calculate $E[||y^2||]$.
$$||y^2||=y^Ty  \Rightarrow E\left[y^{2}\right]= E\left[\theta^{T}H^{T}H\theta\right]$$
Is there any way to open up the brackets such that we can write the norm as a multiplication of $\Sigma_\theta $ by some matrix?

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the the $\operatorname{Tr} \left( \cdot \right)$ operator.

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left[ {\left\| \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} \right] & = \mathbb{E} \left[ \boldsymbol{y}^{T} \boldsymbol{y} \right] \\
& = \mathbb{E} \left[ \operatorname{Tr} \left( \boldsymbol{y} \boldsymbol{y}^{T} \right) \right] \\
& = \operatorname{Tr} \left( \mathbb{E} \left[ \boldsymbol{y} \boldsymbol{y}^{T} \right] \right) \\ 
& = \operatorname{Tr} \left( \mathbb{E} \left[ \boldsymbol{H} \boldsymbol{\theta} \boldsymbol{\theta}^{T} \boldsymbol{H}^{T} \right] \right) \\ 
& = \operatorname{Tr} \left( \boldsymbol{H} \mathbb{E} \left[  \boldsymbol{\theta} \boldsymbol{\theta}^{T} \right] \boldsymbol{H}^{T} \right) \\
& = \operatorname{Tr} \left( \boldsymbol{H} {\sigma}_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}^{2} \boldsymbol{I} \boldsymbol{H}^{T} \right) \\ 
& = {\sigma}_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}^{2} \operatorname{Tr} \left( \boldsymbol{H} \boldsymbol{H}^{T} \right)
\end{align*}
$$